# Как сказать одним словом "человек, который подделывает документы"?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Как сказать одним словом "человек, который подделывает документы"? Что-то типа фальшивомонетчик, но в отношении документов.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я перевела это слово со своего языка на ваш, и мне словарь дает "фальсификатор"...

Answer (score 2):

**фармазон - мошенник, подделывающий документы**. *Феня*.

*Здесь <в тюрьме> Шурик был уже третий или четвертый раз, проходил он по делам все больше незначительным - карман да **фармазон** - и считался человеком неопасным, заключенным сносным, хотя и баламутом.* Высоцкий, Роман о девочках.

[**Исторический словарь галлицизмов русского языка**](http://gallicismes.academic.ru/39500/%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD)

Comment: Фармазон (жарг.) - мошенник, аферист (из словаря ненормативной лексики). А вообще  это слово употреблялось еще в 19 веке и имело тогда значение "безбожник, атеист, еретик", например:  И в бога, говорит, не верит, и в церковь не ходит ― фармазон. [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. (1872-1876)] Попросту сказать, он был атеист, то есть фармазон и отчасти волтерианец. [А. А. Бестужев-Марлинский. (1830)].

Comment: Да, конечно, эти определения я тоже видела. Но то, что я привела в ответе, - одно значение из нескольких, третье. Разве ссылка не читается? Или я что-то поняла не так? Поправьте меня - буду благодарна.

Comment: Помнится, в школе при разборе "Онегина" учили, что это "франк-масон" (... он пьёт одно стаканом красное вино) - в вольной транскрипции с французского, то есть "не нашей веры" человек. Так и у Даля.

Comment: И мне помнится. Только прошло почти двести лет... Есть в ответе и в словаре пометка - "феня". Есть и такое: " Вы фармазон хуже Хрущева. Хрущев мне гарантировал целиком построить коммунизм к восьмидесятому году, а вы - кончить ремонт за две недели. Но прошло уже три. Так чем вы отличаетесь от того лысого фармазонщика с кукурузой?"

Comment: Вопрос был конкретный: человек, который подделывает документы, наверное из нормативной лексики, а в словаре: ФАРМАЗОН, -Устар. =Франкмасон. // Вольнодумец, нигилист. * Сейчас слово перешло в жаргон, но с широким значением - мошенник, аферист всякого рода. Вот пример из литературы: Кто не платит ― тот вор, фармазон.  Санька твой иезуит, а Сережка фармазон, и пропьют они добро мое, промотают!. И т.д. Конкретно о подделке документов речи нет, хотя люди такого рода и документы подделывают. Но это жаргон, а вот фальшивомонетчик - нормативное слово.

Comment: @shampar За что же Вы нас с Н.И.Епишкиным "наказали"?  В вопросе никак не было, как утверждает Сибилла: "Вопрос был конкретный: человек, который подделывает документы, наверное из нормативной лексики..."   Чем же фармазон хуже малявщика? Я пыталась отстоять свою точку зрения и точку зрения автора словаря исторических галлицизмов русского языка. НИКАК не могу понять: неужели ситуация, когда  участник с ГЛОБАЛЬНЫМ рейтингом обращается к словарю - это нормально, а когда дилетант - мы его за предыдущие двести лет отчитываем?!

Answer (score 1):

Фальсификатор - тот, кто занимается фальсификацией, подделкой (по Ожегову).

Comment: @ЛюдмилаИгнатенко - пишите чуть подробнее  - тогда и претензий подобных предыдущей меньше будет. Ответ в принципе ваш понятен. Но он уже был - и был принят как правильный. Вы ничего не добавили.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, "малявщик" - от "малява" - документ (жарг.), поскольку слова, означающие специфический род деятельности, когда нет другого синонима, формируются, в том числе, и с помощью добавления "-щик"?

Comment: Малявщик -  это художник, от малявы, которая рисунок (укр. "малюнок"), а не от малявы, которая документ

Comment: Малява = письмо, записка, весточка («малява от Люськи — передать корешу»).

Comment: А у малявщика не может быть несколько значений, как у той же малявы?